# How can I get CORS to work for API calls with a Hapi v20 server with HTTPS?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

Basic problem: you've followed the tutorial, you've fired up the Hapi server, it's running... *but it doesn't work*. A direct call via curl will get something, using a web browser to directly load the API call will get something... but using that API endpoint within an app, say, Angular or React, and it bombs out with an error message like:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:3000/server/ping' from origin 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

And it's true: you check the headers, and Access-Control-Allow-Origin is **not** on that list at all. So your app, having gotten blocked here in the preflight request, isn't even going to make the actual GET/POST call.

Here's the full file of a fully working Hapi v20.2.0 server, in TypeScript:

```js
'use strict'

import * as fs                    from 'fs'
import * as util                  from 'util'
import * as path                  from 'path'
import * as os                    from 'os'

import * as Hapi                  from '@hapi/hapi'
import * as Http2                 from 'http2'

const strFullNameCert:string=path.resolve(
    os.homedir(),
    'ssl',
    'domain.crt')
const strFullNameKey:string=path.resolve(
    os.homedir(),
    'ssl',
    'domain.key')
const key :Buffer = fs.readFileSync(strFullNameKey)
const cert:Buffer = fs.readFileSync(strFullNameCert)
const sslDetails ={key,cert}

const server = new Hapi.server({
    listener: Http2.createSecureServer(sslDetails), // optional: remove this line for http1.1
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000,
    tls: sslDetails,
    routes: {
        cors: true
        },
    })

console.log(`Host   : ${server.info.host}`)
console.log(`Port   : ${server.info.port}`)
console.log(`Method : ${server.info.protocol}`)
console.log(`Hapi   : v${server.version}`)

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path:'/server/ping',
    handler: async (request, reply) => {
        console.log(`>>>ROUTE>>>  : ${request.route.path}`);
        const response = reply.response({ qSuccess: true, qResult: 'pong' })
        return response;
        }
    })

server.start()
```

To reiterate, this code will "work", it will serve up a response if you load the /server/ping route in an independent way. If you were building a web server to serve pages, this would likely be sufficient to get going.

**This code will still fail CORS validation in a web app.** Why? Because the request to /server/ping is never even going to be made. The app will send a preflight OPTIONS request first. And there's nothing in this code to handle that. So *nothing* you do in the server.route area, messing with route options, or adding headers, is going to fix this. Ten jillion different setups in the main server instantiation of routes:cors wont fix this, because they also don't address the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

I added these, at the top of my middleware, to respond to options(pre-flight) request.
Might cause problems in other areas of the app that use the options, but worked for my case/issue.

```
async function(request: Request, h: ResponseToolkit) {
  if (request.method === "options") {
    const response = h.response({});
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    return h.response(response).takeover();
  }

  // more checks....
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there isn't a route set up that's dealing with the OPTIONS request that Chrome/Firefox will send *before* they attempt the GET/POST to the API being served up by Hapi. Add this code to the above file, just above server.start()

```js
server.route({
    method : 'OPTIONS',
    path: '/{any*}',
    handler : async (request, reply) => {
        console.log(`======options: ${request.route.path}`)
        const response = reply.response({})
        response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',   '*')
        response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',  '*')
        return response;
        }
    })
```

Now you'll see that when you attempt to use the API from your app, it's going to make *two* calls: first, the options call, and then *if that passes* (and with these headers it now will) it will make the actual call you're interested in.

The "cors:true" route option, it really *feels* like it's going to "enable cors". I mean, yes... but really, no. Think of it more like it *permits* Hapi to do cors... you still have to do the work of "handling cors".

Comment: This is not really the correct answer. While you certainly can make a custom `OPTIONS` handler, hapi is designed to respond to `OPTIONS` requests automatically on its own, without developer intervention. I'm guessing that your problem has something to do with the custom HTTP2 listener.

Comment: As far as I know, that's the standard, built-into-node listener for HTTP2. However, using it or not did not change Hapi's lack of response. If there's a working method for Hapi v20 to support SSL and HTTP2 and respond to OPTIONS, I'd love to look at an example. "It should work" isn't the stackoverflow tradition, help me out brother. :)

Comment: Here is a live example of CORS with hapi that I made for you. I didn't try with HTTP2, as you stated that your setup isn't working even with HTTP1.1. Hopefully this will help. If not, I suspect you are using a self-signed SSL certificate that is not trusted by your browser, so make sure the browser trusts it and you can see the API response when visiting the API directly (without CORS coming into play).
https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-bash-ydmlj?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Thank you for your effort! However, you've misread my post: the above initial server I posted works, with both http1.1 or http2. I got your code running on a fully resolved machine with LetsEncrypt certbot cert: I'm sorry, it does not fix the problem. It parallels many existing examples (and my working top version) in that it will serve data if asked directly. Your API server, like my top version without the OPTIONS route, fails when called from in an app like Angular where Chrome is going to enforce CORS with same error message: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'header sent for OPTIONS request.

Comment: So if I add React to my example, you'll consider it valid proof?

Comment: Proof of what? Your code does what you says it will do, but to appease Angular in Chrome it actually needs to respond to the options request. I don't see your client making that options request. It calls directly, which is what I've said works for everything this whole time. I can only say your server, running here, didn't respond to the options request when my Angular app called your server, for the same URL. I also can't find anything on hapi.dev that says "hapi will send a response with x,y,z for a preflight options request". If you've seen that over there, would love to read it. 

Comment: Proof that hapi's CORS handling works and that you don't need to create a route like you've done. I have updated the CodeSandbox so the API request includes a non-safelisted header, which triggers an `OPTIONS` preflight request. The API server is configured to allow only that extra header by name, but you could instead do `headers: '*'`, if you wanted to (just be aware, that won't work if the request includes credentials). I can also add React if necessary, but it shouldn't make a difference.